# Change view alternative

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have an window based app with some ViewController.

I switch from one view to another using :

```
[self.view addSubview:newViewController.view];
```

Everything works fine but I have a problem:

When I change the view to a scrollView which has frames more than 320x480 I can not return to previous frames.I mean I change the the views further normally but I have a bigger frame and I see the rest of the content from the scrollView which is not covered by the current view.

Is there any method to set the superview size back to 320x480?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the frame of a view back to 320X480 manually by doing something like:

```
yourView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
```

When you switch back are you removing the scrollview from the superview as well? [scrollview removeFromSuperView]; ?

Comment: I tried [scrollview removeFromSuperView] but it works only if I move back to usual view immediately after the scrollview.The problem persists when I add subviews of more scrollview, in this case removeFromSuperView removes only the last scrollView.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand your problem then. If you have multiple scrollviews that you are switching between do you have a reference to each of them? ScrollView1, ScrollView2, etc? If you did this you could keep a clean view stack and have all removed that you don't want. Without knowing more its hard to say but you may also want to consider a different navigation layout if it is becoming a mess to swap out views on one view controller